# adding a pandas dataframe to multiple sql tables(one table has forienkey relationship from other table)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to upload a pandas dataframe to sql table through sqlalchemy.I am supposed to insert few columns of the dataframe to a sql table and then read the primary id and based on the id insert other columns to another table. so far I've tried:

```
df1= df[['date','name','email','contact']]
before inserting the dataframe:
df['recordid']=  pd.read_sql_query('select MAX(recordid)+1 from table1', conn).iloc[0, 0] +range(len(df))
and then:
df1.to_sql('table1',conn, if_exists='append',index=False)

after inserting the dataframe1 which is a subset of main dataframe:
I'm adding date column to the main df as that is a notnull column in the table:
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
df['enterdate'] = current_date
df2 = df[['date', 'recordid', 'ph.no', 'email', 'enterdate', 'query']]
df.to_sql('table2',conn, if_exists='append', index=False')
```

Actually in the table2 record id is a foreign key from table 1.

The method I've tried is resulting in Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__leadentr__28702C40B5AB9B80'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object error.

Not able to understand if any better approach and where I am going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the field to allow for non-unique values. With this, the error should disappear.